# Opacity and z-index in elements

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have a site with a dropdown menu. When the menu expands it goes behind some li that i have later on. The `z-index` on the li is 10 and currently the dropdown ul does not have a z-index but it has `opacity:1`. Tried every combination of opacities and z-indexes in the mentioned elements but i cannot make it work as expected. I want the li to be behind the dropdown ul when it expands. The li is relatively positioned (my design needs that) and has a float property. The only way i can make this work is by using `z-index:1` for the li but i don't want that as it messes up with some other elements. Any ideas?

Comment: Seems like i cannot reproduce my error in fiddle. I will look into my code in more detail in case i have missed something . Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the `z-index` property, we must put on the div `position:absolute;`,  `position:fixed;` or `position:relative;`

Answer (score 0):

You should maybe take a look at your positions tags,

If you don't give position value to your elements in your css, then your z-index value will not be considered by the browser.